# Rails nested resource join security best practices

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, security, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I've started a new project which requires accounts to be able to view their candidates and related tasks.

account.rb

```
has_many :candidates
```

candidate.rb

```
has_many :tasks
belongs_to :account
```

task.rb

```
belongs_to :candidate
```

Routes are set up to allow /candidates/4/tasks/3 where account X has access to candidate 4 which has task 3.

tasks_controller.rb is currently like:

```
def show
  @task = Task.find params[:id]
end
```

**QUESTION: What is the best practice approach to ensure that other accounts don't have access to task 3?**

One idea might be something like this but seems very messy:

```
def show
  @task = Account.find(current_account).candidates.find(params[:candidate_id]).tasks.find(params[:id)
end
```

So if the join fails, you don't have access.

Another way might be done using **scopes**. Where you make sure all tasks queried are joined with candidates and current_account.

I could also do a **before_filter** to do a standalone query on candidates table to check that the account has access. This will add an extra query so not ideal.

I'm waffling here... but would love to know how others go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it by rails way...

current_account = Account.find params[:id]

@tasks = current_account.candidates.collect(&:tasks)

This will do your job.

Comment: If there are other tables from candidates, e.g candidates.invoices, candidates.messages etc. Can you think of a neat way to add a global scope rather than having to do @foo = current_account.candidates.foos in ever controller?

Comment: don't get this answer. It seems like it makes multiple SELECT queries due to candidates.collect - Am I misunderstanding something? =)

Comment: @sebastyuiop u should use cancan gem to control accessibility.In Ability Model u can define can :manage, task , candidates_id : current_account.candidate_ids .

Comment: @JakobDamJensen yeah it makes multiple select query, First it selects all candidates of current account and then it selects tasks for each candidates.

Comment: @AnilMaurya my point exactly. When visiting the page it doesn't make sense to me that all candidates should be fetched. Only the one with id=candidate_id should be used.. Right? =) So why is the approach in the show method incorrect? I'm new in Rails - so I might be missing something important.. Sorry in advance =)

Comment: @JakobDamJensen current_account.candidates will fetch all candidates where candidate_id = id .